# Dodge Dakota 2001 power steering pump failed multiple times

Tags: dodge, power-steering, dakota

A few months ago, the power steering fluic squirted all over my engine compartment, on the underside of hood and smoking on the engine. Mechanic replaced it. A day later, the pump failed while driving, lost power steering, no leaks. Same mechanic replaced it for free. Then about a month later, check engine light came on, had another mechanic look at this (I was out of town), there was a code about the power steering pump, he reset it at the time because he was closing. I drove it around for about a month, then today, the pump is back to squirting all inside the engine compartment. What can be causing all this?

Comment: Sounds like something that affects the PS pump but isn't in or of the pump. I'd examine the PS mounts: a mount or mounts might be broken, or loose, or hold the pump in a position which is not aligned with the belt that drives it. Any of these could add significant stress to the pump, as could a failure or wear of the belt tensioner.

Answer (score 1):

A common cause of multiple pump failures is debris in the system. The first pump fails depositing shrapnel in the fluid. Without a complete flush of the system the debris will contaminate and destroy the new pump and the cycle starts again.